# Docker scripts update files whitout build again

Tags: python, docker

I have a question about how I can use docker in order to run simples python scripts. I have a directory with some python scripts, and I create a Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

ENV PYTHONIOENCODING UTF-8

ADD . /
WORKDIR ./

RUN pip install pandas

CMD [ "python", "./hello.py" ]
```

then I build using:

`docker build -t hello.`

and run with: `docker run hello``

My question is about change the `hello.py` file without build again.

Any tip here ?

Answer (score 1):

I would prepare `docker-compose` for that. And then mount `hellp.py` from host to container. I am not sure whether it's possible to update running `hello.py` on the fly.

So my way would be:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  hello:
   image: hello
   volumes: 
     - /home/host/app/hello.py:/hello.py
```

So everytime you will do a change in `hello.py` yo**u won't have to rebuild image** just `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` to reflect changes in your `.py` application.

If you have more than one file you can mount whole directory.